# How to hide the repeater carousel on the page,Kentico

Tags: c#, repeater, kentico

I wanted to know how can i hide a repeater carousel on a webpage, i have tried uncheck the visibility option on the control property, which removes the carousel as whole. I wanted to implement visibility = false .

Comment: If you want it on the page, but invisible, you should specify that in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ticking or unticking the checkbox will set the visibility to false on the webpart.  If you want to hide or show it conditionally with a macro, you'd need to specify a bit more what those conditions would be.

A good example would be `{%ViewMode == 'LiveSite'%}` will show the webpart only on the live site and not in any other mode.

Comment: So is there any way i can have it on my page but hidden?

Comment: Yes, uncheck the box.  Or do you mean you want the html to render but just not display?  If so, on the parent element set the css style to be something like `style="display: none;"`

Comment: Make sense, i just wanted to know if the webpart property itself has some options for that, thanks appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You can add to repeater Web part properties\HTML Envelope:

Content before: `<div style="visibility: hidden;">`

Content after: `</div>`